# echo mysql results in $mail->body of PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to echo the results of a MySQL query into the body of an email to send via PHPMailer, but am having difficulties. The query works as I successfully create the table on the page, but can't seem to get the assigning the table to a variable correct.

My Code:

```
  $mail->Body= 

$html_string = '<html><body><table><thead><tr><th>Food</th><th>Quantity</th> <th>Category</th><tr></thead><tbody>';

        $db1 = new mysqli("localhost","dbname","dbname","password");
        $sql1 = "select * from tbldatingusermaster order by userid desc";
        $result1 = $db1->query($sql1);
        while($data1 = $result1->fetch_object()){
    $html_string .= 
  '<tr><td>'.$data1->name.'</td><td>'.$data1->name.'</td><td>'.$data1->name.'</td></tr>';
}
$html_string .= '</tbody></table></body></html>';

  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the final string to the $mail->Body;

Add this at the end of the file:

```
$mail->Body = $html_string;
```

Although you think you are adding it as the first line states

```
$mail->Body =
...some code here
; //You think this closes the line and assigns value to the $mail->Body
//but that is not true
```